# Where should I integrate AWS credentials in my php framework?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using php mini framework https://github.com/panique/mini

Right now I have the following in the index method in my controller. But it feels like should be better to have it in my config/config.php file. How do I do that so I can use it in my controller/model?

```
// Instantiate the S3 client with your AWS credentials
        $client = S3Client::factory(array(

        'key' => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',

        ));
```

**Update**

I have now tested two different methods but it is not working. My keys are of course correct.

*Using the AWS credentials file and credential profiles*

Created a new file in `~/.aws/credentials/credentials.ini` with the following code:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

But I'm not sure where in the project I should Instantiate a client. I have tested to put the following code in config.php and in my controller but it's not working.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;    
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
        'profile' => 'default',
        'region'  => 'us-west-1',
    ));
```

*Using a configuration file with the service builder*

I put this code in config.php

```
return array(
    // Bootstrap the configuration file with AWS specific features
    'includes' => array('_aws'),
    'services' => array(
        // All AWS clients extend from 'default_settings'. Here we are
        // overriding 'default_settings' with our default credentials and
        // providing a default region setting.
        'default_settings' => array(
            'params' => array(
                array(
                    'credentials' => array(
                        'key'    => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                        'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
                    )
                ),
                'region' => 'us-west-1'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And in my controller where I what to access aws I write this in the top of the file.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
$s3Client = S3Client::factory('APP . '/config/config.php');
$client = $s3Client->get('s3');
```

But I get the error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Aws\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The
>   config must be provided as an array or Collection.'

Comment: Please don't use panique's code as example. It is terrible and has nothing to do with MVC architectural pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Providing Credentials to the SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html) section of the AWS SDK for PHP User Guide. Parts 1, 2, and 3 on that page describe techniques of setting up your credentials without putting them into you application's code or repo.

Comment: This is the best way.  My preference is `Using a configuration file with the service builder`   Also this document specifically states your concern ". However, be careful to not hard-code your credentials inside of your applications. Hard-coding your credentials can be dangerous, because it is easy to accidentally commit your credentials into an SCM repository, potentially exposing your credentials to more people than intended. It can also make it difficult to rotate credentials in the future."

Comment: I have now tested by two methods (updated my question) but it does not work. What am I doing wrong? Guessing that the error is because I do not know where in my code I should instantiate a client.

Comment: Config files are for the the `Aws\Common\Aws` class only, it looks like you are mixing up two code samples from the documentation. Try this way: 

    use Aws\Common\Aws;
    $aws = Aws::factory('APP . '/config/config.php');
    $s3Client = $aws->get('s3');

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried requiring the composer autoloader

`require 'vendor/autoload.php'`

Then you can instantiate your client anywhere in your project